# Move Roblox Group with Script

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to clone a group and set its position to a set place. I can only get it to move a specific part in the group with .Position, but I need the whole group to move. Are there any easy ways to do this? I am doing this in a regular script inside ServerScriptStorage which seems to be fine. Here's my code:
local localCharacters = game.Players.LocalPlayer

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    local HRP = Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

    local ClonedPart = game.ReplicatedStorage.BaseParts:Clone() -- Gives nil when not set to BaseParts.Part
    ClonedPart.Parent = workspace
    ClonedPart.Position = Vector3.new(0, 15, 0)
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SetPrimaryPartCFrame` or `PivotTo` depending on your preference. I previously recommended `SetPrimaryPartCFrame`, but it got deprecated. `PivotTo` is mostly a backwards compatible replacement, so it should be used instead now. Your model should have a primary part set, with the PrimaryPart property. I'm also assuming that BaseParts is a model, and your code errors when you set the Position property.

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    local HRP = Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

    local ClonedPart = game.ReplicatedStorage.BaseParts:Clone()

    ClonedPart:PivotTo(CFrame.new(Vector3.new(0, 15, 0))) --Always set other properties before the parent
    ClonedPart.Parent = workspace
end)
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that `SetPrimaryPartCFrame` got deprecated around a month ago. It should work when `PivotTo` is called instead of `SetPrimaryPartCFrame` without any other changes.